# Authorizing administrators and regular users in a CakePHP application

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, roles

I'm trying to write some simple functionality to distinguish between administrators and regular users in the CakePHP application I'm writing. I've changed my `users` table to have a field called `admin` which is either `0` or `1`.

In `AppController.php` I've got a `$components` array set up like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Blowfish' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

And also this method:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Check if admin
    if(isset($this->params['admin']) && $this->Auth->user('admin') == 1) {
        echo "admin";
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

When I load pages I get this error: `(net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`. For some reason the code above is causing infinite redirects and I can't work out why.

Also, I've set up a routing prefix for `admin` so administrators can access URLs like `/admin/users/edit`. When I go to that page, I don't get infinite redirects and `admin` is `echo`'d out like it should be.

I've read up on tutorials online and read the Cake docs but they all seem to end with the infinite redirects, how can I set this up so that I can distinguish administrators from regular users, and deny/allow access to certain actions for each role?

Comment: Are you using $this->Auth->allow(); correctly? To answer this question supply more code please of your beforefilters and routing rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sixthpoint has already pointed this out.

In absence of the Auth object, the Auth component is redirecting to the Pages Controller and I think you are missing

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow("*"); // * or array("actions", "that", "are", "allowed")
}
```

So, this is essentially creating an infinite loop, First Auth object is missing, it gets directed to PagesController. The Auth component has been configured to authorize all Controllers, incl PagesController. And the loop reiterates redirecting again to PagesController.

Have you tried looking into [ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) ? You can accomplish the same by use of Roles coupled with ACL.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to use `allow()` properly, plus the "default deny" in my `isAuthorized()` method was causing some trouble. I've switched to using `beforeFilter()` in my controllers to allow each action individually for more finely-grained control and it's working well now.